# Validate Resource for PUT action

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

For People resource, I would have POST/PUT/GET/DELETE action on this resource. The resource is defined as below:

```
class People {
    @NotBlank
    String name;
    @Min(18)
    String age;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=10, max=150)
    String address;
}
```

With Spring MVC and Hibernate,

For POST action, I can validate resource by @Valid

But for PUT action, request body just contains 
    {
        "address": "123 Keangnan, Hoan Kiem, Hanoi, Vietnam"
    }

How can I validate resource for PUT action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation group, and all your constraints to first group, e.g. *PeopleValidationGroup*, and add additional join your address property constraints to the second group (named e.g. AddressValidationGroup). Further on you would validate both cases using the *[@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)* annotation, with the appropriate group specified

Check the example in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "firstCase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String firstCase(@Validated(People.PeopleValidationGroup.class) People people, Errors errors) {
       ...
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "secondCase", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String secondCase(@Validated(People.AddressValidationGroup.class) People people, Errors errors) {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Master Slave. It is what I'm looking for